# Receiving error when creating new app using create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

For some reason when trying to create a new app using create react app, it results in errors everytime. Anybody know what's going on?

**Error Stack**
[image: error stack]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the additional `--use-npm` flags at the end?

```js
npx create-react-app user-onboarding
cd user-onboarding
npm start
```

[Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Edit: Yeah, reading your errors in the screenshot it appears that the `--use-npm` flag is causing it to use npm which has outdated versions available, but `npx` always finds the newest versions. Which is a big reason it is the preferred method for installing `create-react-app`

If you have your heart set on using `npm` you can always do an `npm update` before running it again.